# Removing the enumerator from json file using Python

Tags: python, json

The following code generates a json file, however, I need to get rid of the enumerator element in the output **(i.e. "1":, "2":, etc.)**. It looks like a dumb question but I'm totally confused! 
The output looks like this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "found": "Alaska",
        "resolved as": " alaska",
        "gazetteer": " {com.novetta.clavin.gazetteer.LazyAncestryGeoName@59b62d}",
        "position": "  795",
        "confidence": "  1.000000",
        "fuzzy": "  false",
        "lon": " -150.00028",
        "lat": " 64.00028"
    }, ...
```

And here is the code:

```
 import json
 filename = 'output.txt'
 dict1 = {}
 fields = ['found', 'resolved as', 'gazetteer', 'position', 'confidence', 'fuzzy', 'lon', 'lat' ]
 with open(filename) as fh:
      
     l = 1
   
     for line in fh:
       
     # reading line by line from the text file
        description = list( line.strip().split(','))
       
     # for output see below
        print(description) 
       
     # for automatic creation of id for each employee
        sno = '' + str(l)
   
     # loop variable
       i = 0
     # intermediate dictionary
       dict2 = {}
       while i<len(fields):
           
             # creating dictionary for each employee
             dict2[fields[i]]= description[i]
             i = i + 1
               
     # appending the record of each employee to
     # the main dictionary
     dict1[sno]= dict2
     l = l + 1
# creating json file        
out_file = open("test2.json", "w")
json.dump(dict1, out_file, indent = 4)
out_file.close()
```

Comment: You need to append your dict values into a list and ignore the global dict keys.

Comment: The line `dict1[sno] = dict2` is the one responsible for storing `dict2` under a '1' "enumerator" key. So why not just do `json.dump(dict2, out_file, indent=4)` directly?

Comment: Did you write this code? Why did you choose to produce JSON from a dictionary `dict1`?

Comment: What *should* the output look like?

Comment: So you didn’t write this code, and you’re asking on StackOverflow for someone to modify it or you. StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service; please show an honest attempt to solve this problem yourself, and if it doesn’t work then edit your on code into your question and explain what’s wrong with the output it produces.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the enumerator, there should only be one dictionary. Here is the new code which converts a text file to json:

```
import json
filename = 'output.txt'
fields = ['found', 'resolved as', 'gazetteer', 'position', 'confidence', 'fuzzy', 
'lon', 'lat' ]

dic1 = {}
with open(filename) as fh:
     
    for line in fh:
      
    # reading line by line from the text file
    description = list( line.strip().split(','))
      
    
    print(description) 
    
      for lines in description:    
          for key in fields:
              for value in description:
                  dic1[key] = value
                  description.remove(value)
                  break
                
        
            #print (str(dic1))
              json_string = json.dumps(dic1)
              print(json_string)
```

Now, the output in the json file looks like this (without the enumerator (i.e. key):

> {"found": "Alaska", "resolved as": " alaska", "gazetteer": " {com.novetta.clavin.gazetteer.LazyAncestryGeoName@59b62d}", "position": "  56332", "confidence": "  1.000000", "fuzzy": "  false", "lon": " -150.00028", "lat": " 64.00028"}